# textfield or textarea with in rowbodytpl of extjs grid (rowexpander)

Tags: extjs, extjs5

How can I create textfield or textarea with in rowbodytpl of extjs grid (rowexpander). Also my program needs to read these fields and update the DB. I would love to know the use of radiogroup within rowbodytpl

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way is to implement plugin which can render any component into rowbody. Then you can just pass any component config to it.

Example plugin:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.grid.SubCmp', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.plugin.RowExpander',

    alias: 'plugin.subcmp',

    rowBodyTpl: ['{%this.owner.renderComponent(out, values);%}'],

    // override this method and return component config
    componentConfigFn: function(record) { return {}; },

    init: function(grid) {
        var me = this,
            store = grid.getStore(),
            view = grid.getView();

        me.components = {};
        me.callParent(arguments);

        // when grid is reloaded we should destroy all created components
        grid.on('beforedestroy', me.destroyComponents, me);
        store.on('beforeload', me.destroyComponents, me);

        // renders component
        view.on('expandbody', me.onExpandBody, me);

        // modify getRefItems method of grid to allow querying components from rowbody
        grid.getRefItems = (function() {
            var originalFn = grid.getRefItems;
            return function(deep) {
                var result = originalFn.call(grid, deep);

                if (deep) {
                    for (var i in me.components) {
                        result.push(me.components[i]);
                        result.push.apply(result, me.components[i].getRefItems(true));
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }
        }());    
    },

    destroyComponents: function() {
        var me = this,
            components = me.components;

        for (var i in components) {
            components[i].destroy();
        }
        me.components = {};
    },

    onExpandBody: function(rowNode, record, expandRow, eOpts) {
        var me = this,
            grid = me.grid,
            recordId = record.id,
            componentWrapId = grid.id + '-component-wrap-' + recordId,
            component = me.components[recordId];

        if (component && !component.rendered) {
            component.render(componentWrapId);
        }
    },

    renderComponent: function (out, rowValues) {
        var me = this,
            grid = me.grid,
            store = grid.getStore(),
            recordId = rowValues.id,
            record = store.getById(recordId),
            componentWrapId = grid.id + '-component-wrap-' + recordId,
            componentId = grid.id + '-component-' + recordId,
            component,
            config;

        if (me.components[recordId]) {
            return; // already rendered
        }

        config = Ext.apply({}, { id: componentId }, me.componentConfigFn(record));
        me.components[recordId] = component = Ext.create(config);

        out.push('<div id="' + componentWrapId + '"></div>');
    }
});
```

To select components from rowbody, you can use `grid.query` method.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/znnqxmyq/9/

Comment: This will not work if the grid records will ever invoke a set on them. The set triggers a change event in the store that in turn syncs the row template that removes the component node from the grid...